# Array of strings C

Tags: arrays, c, string, struct, malloc

**I have a problem with the two printf inside the function**, the code stops at  `megainput[val1-1] = strdup(input);`, what's wrong? (value minimum of val1 is 1) I didn't write the readCommand function because has no problem. The final program is a list where every node->string points to a zone of megainput.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 1025
char input[N];
char **megainput=NULL;
struct Node 
{
    char *string;
    struct Node* before; 
    struct Node* after; 
}*starter;
                                                            //creo il nodo di testa starter
void delete();
void change(int val1, int val2){
    int intervallo=val2-val1+1;
    struct Node* nodo = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    fgets(input, 1025, stdin);
    megainput[val1-1] = strdup(input);   //error here
    printf("%s ",input);
    nodo->string = megainput[val1-1];
    printf("%s",nodo->string);
    
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    starter = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    starter->string=NULL;
    starter->before = NULL; 
    starter->after = NULL;
    char *command;                          //dubbio
    int *val1;
    int *val2;
    while (1)
    {
       readCommand(&command, &val1, &val2);
       change(val1, val2);
     }
    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: You've never allocated any memory for `megainput`, you can't assign to `megainput[val1-1]`.

Comment: @Barmar i've read that strdup does the same, i'm wrong?

Comment: That allocates memory for the string, not the array of pointers to the strings.

Answer (score 1):

`strdup()` copies the string in `input()`, but you need to allocate memory for the array of pointers `megainput()`.

```
#define N 1025
char input[N];
char **megainput=NULL;
size_t megainput_max = -1;
struct Node 
{
    char *string;
    struct Node* before; 
    struct Node* after; 
}*starter;
                                                            //creo il nodo di testa starter
void delete();
void change(int val1, int val2){
    int intervallo=val2-val1+1;
    struct Node* nodo = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    fgets(input, N, stdin);
    if (val1-1 > megainput_max) { // Need to add more to megaainput
        char **temp = realloc(megainput, val1 * sizeof(*megainput));
        if (!temp) {
            printf("Memory allocation failure\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        megainput = temp;
        megainput_max = val1 - 1;
    }
    megainput[val1-1] = strdup(input);   //error here
    printf("%s ",input);
    nodo->string = megainput[val1-1];
    printf("%s",nodo->string);
    
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    starter = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    starter->string=NULL;
    starter->before = NULL; 
    starter->after = NULL;
    char *command;                          //dubbio
    int *val1;
    int *val2;
    while (1)
    {
       readCommand(&command, &val1, &val2);
       change(val1, val2);
     }
    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: do i also need to pass megainput_max by reference to the function so i can remember the maximum value?

Comment: No, it's a global variable just like `megainput`.

Comment: still having problems. Do i need to do a malloc before realloc? I read that you can use Realloc only if you have already used malloc.

Comment: @AaronCettolin You can also do it if the pointer is `NULL`. Then it's equivalent to `malloc()`. So the first iteration will do the initial allocation.